# Name of structure as the operand of the sizeof

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

When you define a structure like below

```
typedef struct num {
   int a; 
   int b; 
} A;
```

Then `sizeof(A)` is valid, but `sizeof(num)` isn't. Could anyone please explain the reason why the sizeof operator doesn't accept `num`?

Comment: `num` is a tag, not a type. So `sizeof(num)` is invalid, but `sizeof(struct num)` is fine.

Comment: @unwind thank you for the comment! I thought the size of is a function...

Comment: @unwind In this case, `sizeof A` wouldn't work. Since `A` is a type, `sizeof` needs the parentheses.

Comment: @IanAbbott D'oh! Of course, brain error. I'll delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `num` on its own doesn't constitute a *type* in C (only `struct num` or its typedef `A` constitutes the *type*). So, `sizeof` fails as its operand is not in either form of that it's defined for:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

i.e. `num` is neither a *type* nor a *unary-expression*.

So, `sizeof(struct num)` or `sizeof(A)` is fine but `sizeof(num)` isn't.